# Geometrical meaning of $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, quadratic-forms, geometric-interpretation

I am looking for a geometrical interpretation of the symmetrical expression

$$f=x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz\tag{1}$$

with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$. I could for example $f$ interprete as dot products of a vector with its permuted vector

$$f=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\z\\x\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

however I think there are more symmetrical ways to represent $f$ geometrically. Maybe $x,y,z$ can be thought of sides of a triangle, etc. Geometrical interpretations in $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R^2}, \mathbb{R^3}$ are of interest.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)$ is also half the squared distance between points $(x,y,z)$ and $(y,z,x)$.

Comment: @dxiv I was just about to press the button on a nearly identical comment ...

Comment: More generally, an expression of the kind you have given, where all variables have the same degree of two is called a quadratic form.  A quadratic form may be written in matrix form as
$x^TAx$.

Comment: @MarkBennet Leaving it for someone else to develop that into an answer proper ;-)

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx = k$ is an ellipsoid.  You can think of $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - yz - zx$ as a set of concentric ellipsoids.  The value of the function representing which shell any point lies on.  This is also a distance metric that has been distorted from the standard Euclidean distance.

Comment: Useful search: [a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc](https://www.google.com/search?q=a%5E3+%2B+b%5E3+%2B+c%5E3+-+3abc) See also: **[1]** Desmond MacHale, [*My favourite polynomial*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3620243), **Mathematical Gazette** 75 #472 (June 1991), pp. 157-165; **[2]** Mark B. Villarino's 2 January 2013 arXiv paper [*A cubic surface of revolution*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0243.pdf).

Comment: I am not sure if there is a really nice characterization of this in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ However, you let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{C},$ then it's a cute exercise to prove that $x,y,z$ forms an equilateral triangle if and only if:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2 = xy+yz+zx$$

Comment: Consider the Laplacian matrix of the complete graph with $3$ vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render $(x-y)^2=x^2-2xy+y^2$ and similarly for the $x,z$ and $y,z$ pairs. When you add up the squares you get

$2(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz).$

So $x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-xz-yz$ is half the sum of squared distances between three points on a line.

Answer (score 4):

Let $L \subset \Bbb R^3 $ be the line $L = \{ (t,t, t) \mid t \in \Bbb R \}$. The projection of the point $P = (x, y, z) \in \Bbb R^3$ onto $L$ is $(s, s, s)$ with $s = (x+y+z)/3$, and the squared distance from $P$ to $L$ is
$$
 (x-s)^2+(y-s)^2+(z-s)^2 = \frac 23 (x^2+y^2+z^2-xy -yz-zx) \, .
$$

So $f$ is $3/2$ times the squared distance of $(x, y, z)$ to the line $L$.

*Remark:* As mentioned in the comments, $f=\frac{1}{2}\left((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\right)$, so that $f$ is zero exactly if $x=y=z$, that is if $P=(x, y, z)$ lies on the line $L$. That suggests to express $f$ in terms of the distance of $P$ to $L$.